# Organize Observable Collection into Timetable

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have an `ObservableCollection<Performance>` that needs to be displayed in an WPF application in a timetable manner.

**Performances** consist, beside other, of a **StartTime** and and a **Location** and should be organized like this:

```
Location | 14h - 15h | 15h - 16h | 16h - 17h | 17h - 18h
---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
Loc #1   | Perf 1    | Perf 2    | Perf 3    | Perf 4
---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------
Loc #2   | Perf 5    | ...
---------------------+
...
```

My persistence layer guarantees that there are no intersections, i.e. when there is one performance that is located in A and starts a X o'clock, then no other will do so.

I've tried several approaches, mostly with `DataGrid`, since this seems to be the obvious choice, but I wasn't able to accomplish what is desired. I'm pretty sure that there must be some kind of solution that is not totally "hacky" but I didn't figure it out.

Is it possible to use the data as it is or does the `ObservableCollection` need to be restructured in any case? How do I manage to bind the `DataGrid` both on `StartTime` and `Location`? Or should I replace the `DataGrid` anyway?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe you want to share some of you classes & xaml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to is called pivoting, and unfortunately, it's not that easy to do if you don't know the exact columns in advance and want to build everything up from the data.

One solution is to convert your `ObservableCollection` to a `DataTable` every time the data changes, and then have your `DataGrid` control bind to the `DataTable` with `AutoGenerateColumns="true"`.

The `DataTable` class has been around since a very early version of .NET, and is not particularly elegant to use with modern C#, but it does allow you to create columns on the fly, which is the key challenge when pivoting data.

With that said, here is some code to construct a `DataTable` from an `ObservableCollction<Performance>`:

```
private static DataTable GetPerformances(ObservableCollection<Performance> performances)
{
    var dataTable = GetTableSkeleton(performances);
    var performanceGroups = performances
        .GroupBy(x => x.Location)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Key);
    foreach (var performanceGroup in performanceGroups)
    {
        var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
        dataRow["Location"] = $"Loc {performanceGroup.Key}";
        foreach (var performance in performanceGroup)
        {
            var columnName = GetColumnName(performance.StartTime);
            dataRow[columnName] = $"Perf {performance.Id}";
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
    }
    return dataTable;
}

private static DataTable GetTableSkeleton(IEnumerable<Performance> performances)
{
    var timeRanges = performances
        .Select(x => x.StartTime)
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(x => x)
        .Select(x => new DataColumn(GetColumnName(x)))
        .ToArray();
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Columns.Add("Location");
    dataTable.Columns.AddRange(timeRanges);
    return dataTable;
}

private static string GetColumnName(int startTime)
{
    return $"{startTime}-{startTime + 1}";
}
```

What this does is create a "skeleton" `DataTable` by first extracting the column names out of the performances (making sure there are no duplicates and sorting by StartTime), then adding those columns to a fresh `DataTable`. (It also adds the Location column.)

Then, it adds all the data to the table by looping through the data grouped and sorted by location.

You can ensure that your `DataGrid` always stays updated by hooking into the `CollectionChanged` event.

This assumes your `Performance` class has these three integer properties: `Id`, `StartTime`, and `Location`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a closer look at your answer tomorrow